# My CSS classes are applied when in some places but not others

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a simple project getting me used to HTML and CSS, but I am running into an issue with the CSS. It's supposed to look like the Google homepage, without any functionality, just HTML and CSS.

I have tried looking up solutions, and trying some like clearing Google Chrome's cache, but that did not work.

```
    <head>
        <title>Google</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="google-tab-icon.png" class="circle-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="google-style.css" type="text/css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <nav class="nav-links">
                <a href="null">About</a>
                <a href="null">Store</a>
                <a href="null">Gmail</a>
                <a href="null">Images</a>
                <img src="google-acct-img.jpg" alt="Google Account Image"  class="account-image">
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div  class="center google-logo">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google Logo"> 
        </div>
        <form action="search.txt">
            <input type="text" class="center search-bar">
        </form>
   </body>
```

This is the HTML I have, so far it just includes the top navigation links, account profile photo, main Google logo, and the search bar. When I have the classes where they are (in the div/nav tag), none of the CSS is applied, but when I put classes directly in the a tag, or directly in the img tag, they work.

I was just hoping to figure out why the styles are not working in the div/nav tags/what I am doing incorrectly here.
I have also included my (external) CSS file contents below.

```
.center{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.google-logo{
    width: 16.5%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.circle-icon{
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.search-bar{
    width: 25%;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 0%;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.account-image{
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 50px;
}

.nav-links{
    color: rgb(36, 34, 34);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 90%;
}
```

Comment: The children of an Element is not the same as the Element itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the class to the image directly because things within the element won't be styled with the same classes as the inner element if I've understood your question correctly.

```css
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.google-logo {
  width: 16.5%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.circle-icon {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.search-bar {
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.account-image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}

.nav-links {
  color: rgb(36, 34, 34);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Google</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="google-tab-icon.png" class="circle-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="google-style.css" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <nav class="nav-links">
      <a href="null">About</a>
      <a href="null">Store</a>
      <a href="null">Gmail</a>
      <a href="null">Images</a>
      <img class="account-image" src="google-acct-img.jpg" alt="Google Account Image">
    </nav>
  </div>
  <img class="center google-logo" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google Logo">
  </div>
  <form action="search.txt">
    <input type="text" class="center search-bar">
  </form>
</body>
```